# Why is it necessary to access smart contracts via their address?

Tags: solidity, ether, addresses, smart-contract-wallets

I am new to solidity and just started exploring smart contracts.

I have a smart contract for creating a Person struct with name and age and a function to access the structs using the name variable:

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    struct Person {
        string name;
        int age;
    }
    
    mapping(string => Person) private nameLookup;

    function addPerson(string memory name, int age) public {
        nameLookup[name] = Person(name, age);
    }

    function getPerson(string memory name) public view returns(Person memory ret) {
        ret = nameLookup[name];
    }   
}
```

In another contract I have a StorageFactory which deploys a number of SimpleStorage contracts and wraps its functions:

```
contract StorageFactory {
    SimpleStorage[] public storages;

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        storages.push(simpleStorage);
    }

    function addPersonAt(uint256 index, string memory name, int age) public {
        SimpleStorage(address(storages[index])).addPerson(name, age);
    }

    function getPersonFrom(uint256 index, string memory name) public view returns(SimpleStorage.Person memory ret) {
        ret = SimpleStorage(address(storages[index])).getPerson(name);
    }
}
```

In the tutorial I am following they access the smart contract by passing the address of the contract stored in the `storages` array to a `SimpleStorage` constructor.

What is the difference between accessing the smart contract like this and just using the value stored in the array e.g:

```
SimpleStorage myStorage = storages[_index];
```

P.S: I tried both ways and they both seem to work. I could not find any information in the documentation or anywhere else. Any insight will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing, except that the casting part is done implicitly in the second example you provided.